# Any subset of size six from the set $S = \{1,2,3,...,9\}$ must contain two elements whose sum is $10$.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

I encountered into the following problem from Wikipedia from "Pigeonhole principle" page.

> Any subset of size six from the set $S = \{1,2,3,...,9\}$ must contain
>   two elements whose sum is $10$.
>
> **Proof:** The pigeonholes will be labelled by the two element subsets $\{1,9\}, \{2,8\}, \{3,7\}, \{4,6\}$ and the singleton $\{5\}$, five
>   pigeonholes in all. When the six "pigeons" (elements of the size six
>   subset) are placed into these pigeonholes, each pigeon going into the
>   pigeonhole that has it contained in its label, at least one of the
>   pigeonholes labelled with a two element subset will have two pigeons
>   in it.

However I can not comprehend the last sentence of the proof. Suppose we have six element subset of set $S$, call it $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\}$. Since we have $5$ pigeonholes and $6$ pigeons (elements $x_i$) then some pigeonhole (suppose $\{1,9\}$) has at least two elements (suppose $x_1,x_2$). Why then $x_1+x_2=10$?

What if $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\}=\{1,2,4,6,8,9\}$ and for example two elements say $1,2$ are in pigeonhole $\{1,9\}$. But $1+2\neq 10$.

Can anyone explain my question in detail, please?

Comment: $x_1 + x_2$ is only one of the possible sums. $x_1 + x_6 = 10$ though which is the claim, not that all sums are $10$ but that there exists a pair that sum to $10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each pigeon goes into the pigeonhole that matches its label. E.g. pigeon 3 goes into {3,7}. Since there are 5 pigeonholes and 6 pigeons, one of the holes with two labels must end up with 2 pigeons in it.

Does that help?

Comment: That was the answer which I needed! Every pigeon (with some number) goes to the pigeonhole where one of the coordinates $\{x,y\}$ coincides with $m$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is key. It is written very strangely to say the least... I was utterly confused at first reading. Best to have language being simple and direct in math! I'd be tempted to edit the wikipedia entry. Pigeon $m$ has no choice but to go into the pigeonhole ${x,y}$ where either $x=m$ or $y=m$ (with exception for $m=5$, but that doesn't affect anything since pigeon 5 sits all by itself).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear answer! One of the reasons why I did not understand that text maybe that English is not my native language :)

Comment: @RFZ, well, English is my native language and I was thoroughly confused, so don't feel bad!

Answer (score 1):

You are understanding the wrong thing

The principal states that "there exists a pair of solution" , not every pair is solution

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is the following. You divide your set $S$ into 5 parts (here called *pigeonholes*). Note that each part has exactly 2 numbers, and each part sums to 10. Hence, if you have 2 numbers from the same pigeonhole, they will sum to 10.

Now your subset of size 6, say $X$, has the numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_6$. By the pigeonhole principle, at least one pair of these must be from the same pigeonhole, hence they will sum to 10.

So for example if $X = \{1,2, \ldots, 6\}$ then $4$ and $6$ are from the same pigeonhole and must add to 10.

In your sample set $X = \{1,2,4,6,8,9\}$, there are 3 such pairs, but existence of only 1 is guaranteed always.